# Cannot exclude records that doesn't JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return only the competitions that have a ranking, this ranking is located inside the table `league_ranking` and each competition is associated with `round_id` column.

Essentially the query should return all the competitions of a specific country, at the condition that all the competitions of that country must have a ranking, so I did:

```
SELECT c.name AS competition_name,
  c.id AS competition_id
  FROM competition c
  JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.competition_id = c.id
  JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.season_id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN league_ranking l ON l.round_id = r.id
  WHERE c.country_id = :country_id AND l.round_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY c.id
  ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

This query return also the competition which doesn't have any ranking, eg:

*competition*

```
id | country_id | name
202     12         Cup
```

*competition_seasons*

```
id  | competition_id | name
955       202           2018/2019
```

*competition_rounds*

```
id    | season_id |
 2122    955
```

*league_ranking*

no record for that round

The query above will also return the competition `202`, what I did wrong?

Comment: What if you change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`?

Comment: @rad same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query as it stands is specifically designed to only return competitions with *no* league ranking because it uses a `LEFT JOIN` to `league_ranking` and then a check that `l.round_id IS NULL`, which will only be true when a competition has no league ranking (i.e. there is no matching row with `l.round_id = r.id`). If you want *only* competitions that do have a league ranking, change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN` and remove the `l.round_id IS NULL` condition. Note that you don't need a `GROUP BY` clause and I have removed it.

```
SELECT c.name AS competition_name,
  c.id AS competition_id
  FROM competition c
  JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.competition_id = c.id
  JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.season_id = s.id
  JOIN league_ranking l ON l.round_id = r.id
  WHERE c.country_id = :country_id
  ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/adcpqXaFm6sNrJwXJXfw5D/0)

Comment: I already tried that and the competition 202 is always returned but it have no league ranking..

Comment: @sfarzoso that's not possible if there is no record in the league ranking table. You did change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN`?

Comment: Okay I found the problem, there are some rounds of the competition 202 which have rankings.. that's why didn't worked

Comment: @sfarzoso good to hear. I'd just finished creating a demo showing it worked... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/adcpqXaFm6sNrJwXJXfw5D/0

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
SELECT c.name AS competition_name, c.id AS competition_id FROM competition c JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.competition_id = c.id JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.season_id = s.id JOIN league_ranking l ON l.round_id = r.id WHERE c.country_id = :country_id GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY c.name ASC
```